# Access property in firebase security rules

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to make some rules for my firebase console in order to secure my data is valid. For that, I just want to make a simple rule that ensures, that an attribute `authorized` is equal to true is a start.

I'm sending a json payload like this

```
{
"name": "kris", 
 "message": "message",
"authorized": true
}
```

and I have rules like this

```
  {
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
   ".validate": "newData.child('authorized').val() === true"
  }
}
```

I have looked at the documentation, and I have figured, that this seems like the most logical way to access a property in my json payload. But I can't seem to access it, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly allowing write operation:

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".write": true,
   ".validate": "newData.child('authorized').val() === true"
  }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick! I got confused, because that rule, was not specified in the documentation example. Thank you!